# How to set an ID to squares in table using JS

Tags: javascript, css

Right now i have this code, and I need to get ID's for every square in the table, so when it's clicked, it knows wheather there is a bomb or not, and changes color accordingly.

```
function tableCreate(i, j) {
    var body = document.body;
    var table = '<table>';
    var counter = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < ruudud.value; i++) {
        table += '<tr>';

        for (var j = 0; j < ruudud.value; j++) {
            counter++;

            if (i == ruudud.value && j == ruudud.value) {
                break;
            } else {
                table += '<td onclick="leftClick('+ i +','+ j +')"></td>';
            } 
        }
        table += '</tr>'
    }
    document.getElementById('gameField').innerHTML = table;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean every td?
In the leftClick function you could check event.target and get information on that element.

Have a look here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: `ruudud` ??????

Comment: Defining an `id` for every `<td>` is extremely, extremely similiar to how you define the `onclick`. Just do id ;-) And another thing: the `if` inside your 2nd for-loop is useless, it will never go to the break statement as both loops have ended before that could happen.

Comment: I need to get different ID for every td element
td(0,0) id=0
td(0,1) id=1
...
I've only learned JS for 1 week, so everything is quite confusing

Comment: It feels like an XY problem to me: you do not actually need IDs for what you are describing. Using large amount of IDs in the same document dramatically slows down performance because the browser has to create an index to keep track of each unique ID. Instead, you can store the x,y coordinates of each cell in html5 data attributes, e.g. `<td data-x="5" data-y="2">`. If your bomb is at a specific coordinate, simply check it against the dataset of the event target which fired the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution for your request. 
As mentioned by [Keagz93](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3380288/keagz93) you can use the `this` operator in the function as in the example.

As [Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395910/terry) mentioned a large amount of IDs slows down the performance of your website, consequently i added `data-attributes` to store the information as well.

```js
function createTable(){
  var $table = document.createElement('table');
  var squares = parseInt(document.querySelector('#squares').value);
  var cells = 0; 
  
  for(var i = 0; i < squares; i++){
    var $row = document.createElement('tr');
    
    for(var j = 0; j < squares; j++){
      cells++;
      var $cell = document.createElement('td');
      var fnParams = "this," + i + "," + j + "," + cells;
      $cell.innerHTML = cells;
      $cell.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.logTableCell(' + fnParams + ');');
      $cell.setAttribute('data-x', j);
      $cell.setAttribute('data-y', i);
      $row.appendChild($cell);
    }
    $table.appendChild($row);
  }
  document.querySelector('#print').innerHTML = $table.outerHTML;
}
document.querySelector('#create').addEventListener('click', createTable);

window.logTableCell = function(el,i,j,cells) { 
  var dataY = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-y'));
  var dataX = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-x'));
  console.log(el);
  console.log("data-x: " + dataX + " - data-y: " + dataY);
  console.log("i: " + i + " - j: " + j + " - cells: " + cells);
};
```

```html
<input id="squares" value="5"/>
<button id="create">Create</button>
<div id="print"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment: **you do not need to use IDs at all to achieve what you want**. The reason to avoid ID is very simple: you are introducing an unnecessary overhead to your browser, since it has to **index every single element with an ID for it**. Imagine if you have a minefield of size 100-by-100: this means that you have to generate 10,000 unique IDs which the browser has to index.

To create your minefield, you don't even need to rely on `<table>`. You can simply create an array of `<div>` elements (which are floated to the left) and inject it into a parent element. What you need is to simply set the dimensions of the parent so that it can accommodate all the cells snugly.

The logic of creating the DOM is explained after the code snippet, since it is not crucial to the logic we are implementing on the JS side.

I have created an example below, where only a single click event listener is attached: it is attached to the minefield. When any cells within it is clicked on, it simply bubbles up to the minefield. In the callback, we can use `event.target` to retrieve the stored x and y-coordinates of the cell that emitted the click event, and cross-check it against the known position of the bomb.

Note: Remember that when reading from the `.dataset` property, you will need to convert your string into numbers. This can be done simply by prepending a `+` sign to the value, e.g. `+Element.dataset.x`.

```js
// Settings
var width = 10;
var height = 10;
var cellWidth = 20;
var cellHeight = 20;
var randomPosition = function(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
};
var bomb = {
  x: randomPosition(width),
  y: randomPosition(height)
};

// Just so you know where the bomb is
console.log('Bomb is at ('+bomb.x+','+bomb.y+')');

// Create your mine field
var field = document.createElement('div');
field.id = 'field';
document.body.appendChild(field);

// Create cells in your field
// We use documentFragment so that we don't constantly update the DOM when looping
var fieldFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
  var cell = document.createElement('div');
  cell.classList.add('cell');
  cell.style.width = cellWidth + 'px';
  cell.style.height = cellHeight + 'px';
  
  // Calculate x and y coordinates
  var yCoord = Math.floor(i/width);
  var xCoord = i % width;
  
  // Store coordinates in data- attributes
  cell.dataset.x = xCoord;
  cell.dataset.y = yCoord;
  
  // For testing only: highlight cell with bomb, uncomment this to visually hide bomb
  if (xCoord === bomb.x && yCoord === bomb.y)
    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#b13131';
  
  fieldFragment.appendChild(cell);
}

// Style the minefield to fit all cells nicely
field.style.width = width * cellWidth + 'px';
field.style.height = height * cellHeight + 'px';

// Inject created cells all at once
field.appendChild(fieldFragment);

// Bind event listener to the field itself
field.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var clickedCell = e.target;
  if (+clickedCell.dataset.x === bomb.x && +clickedCell.dataset.y === bomb.y)
    console.log('You clicked on a bomb!');
  else
    console.log('You are safe');
});
```

```css
#field {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
#field .cell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

### Creating the DOM

The DOM is created using Document Fragments, because we do not want to inject individual cells to the minefield in the for loop. Document fragments prevents us from triggering browser repaints, which means better browser performance. Only a single repaint event will be triggered, since we actually inject the entire document fragment into your minefield at the end.

Let's say you want a 10x10 minefield. That means you have to create 100 cells. Even though you can create 2 nested for loops, there is really no need for that, since we know:

- the quotient (the rounded down value of `index / width`) is the row index (y-coordinate)
- the remainder (the modulus of `index / width`) is the column index (x-coordinate)

With these coordinates in hand, we can then use the `.dataset` property and store our x and y-coordinates of each cell. This data can then be read by the click event target, so that we can crosschecked the clicked cell's coordinates with the bomb coordinate.